# Is "that" a relative pronoun here?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Is the use of "that" in the sentence below a relative pronoun? It does stand in place of the noun ('view'), but I'm not sure if this is a relative pronoun. Can someone please explain? Thank you.

> It is my view **that** we should legalize abortion.

Answer (score 1):

> *It is my view* [*that we should legalize abortion*].

No, "that" is never a pronoun when it introduces subordinate relative and content clauses, but a subordinator.

In any case, "that" is not anaphorically linked  to "view", so the bracketed constituent is not a relative clause, but a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "view".

Answer (score 0):

It is usually analysed as a *complementizer*, which packages up the sentence "we should legalize abortion" as a noun phrase.

This is easier to see with a context where a noun phrase is normal, eg as the object of a verb:

> I argued that we should legalize abortion.

It's a bit harder to see the role that the NP is playing in this case: in my view it is a complement of "view": "which view? The view that we should legalize abortion".

Comment: Thank you for your answer Colin. I understand that the following sentence is a complementizer, since it doesn't modify any noun: 

"I did not know that she liked balloons." 

However, in my sentence ("It is my view that we should legalize abortion"), the word "that" is modifying the noun. Isn't it? 

E.g. the "who" in this sentence is a relative pronoun: "Tom is the person who gave me these apples." I especially don't understand the last part of your answer. To make a corollary (to the last part of your answer), "who" is  a complement of "person." which person? The person who gave apples

Comment: @ss3592 No, in that sentence _that_ does not modify anything. It is a complementizer introducing the clause _we should legalize abortion_. The whole complement, with _that_, doesn't modify anything, either. It's been displaced from its subject position by Extraposition; the original was _That we should legalize abortion is my view_, and the dummy _it_ was inserted by Extraposition. The other sentence does have a relative clause, but it also has _person_, which is the noun that the relative clause modifies. And "complement" does not mean "coreferent" or "antecedent".

Comment: The term used in another answer is that "that" is known as a "subordinator", also called a coordinating conjunction. From the "Conjunction" article on Wikipedia: '"Complementizers can be considered to be special subordinating conjunctions that introduce complement clauses: e.g. "I hope that he'll be on time"."' Also under the article "Complementizer": "The concept of complementizers is specific to certain modern grammatical theories; in traditional grammar, such words are normally considered conjunctions." Given this information, can "that" be considered simply a subordinating conjunction?

Comment: @Zebrafish Traditional grammars would call it a conjunction or a subjunction; but that would be considered outdated and just plain wrong by most linguists today. Note that subordinators are _not_ coordinating conjunctions but subordinating ones. Coordinators and subordibators are different things.